# Magento 2.2.5 - The price attribute and visibility attributes are not visible in admin panel product editing page

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, magento-2.2.5

`Magento 2.2.5`- The `price and visibility` attributes of `catalog_products` are not visible while going to the product edit page. I want to update the price of the products.

What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Having same issue , Did you found any solution to this ?

Comment: Please reply asap